# Rails mutithreading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have created a new thread inside main thread and running while loop until my global variable changed. But if I change the global variable in main thread it is not reflected in new thread. What will be the problem.

```
Thread.new do     
  loop do  
p "login info"
p logged
mutex.synchronize do
if(!logged)
    break
  else
    begin
   #do something
   sleep 5          
    rescue => e 
    p  e     
    end
  end   
  end
end
```

I have set logged to false in logout method. But the loop is not breaking

module SessionsHelper

logged =false

# Logs in the given user.

def log_in(user)

```
session[:user_id] = user[:id]

storeAuthToken(user)

logged=true
```

end

Comment: can you show where have you defined logged.

Comment: `logged` is local variable for the scope of the thread. You might want to use class/instance variable, but this is definitely a task for a [`Mutex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Mutex.html).

Comment: logged is defined at class level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable has to define as $logged = false